# Angular - does not download all the images from nested array

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to download base64 images to my local machine but it stops after checking first array. it does not download all the images.

```
  public getAllImages() {
    this.installationRequest.installations.forEach((drives: any) => {
      drives.phases.map((phase) => {
        phase.subjects.map((sub) => {
          console.log(sub.base64Image);
          return this._http.get(sub.base64Image, { responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob }).map((res) => {
            return {
              filename: sub.imageName,
              data: res.blob(),
            };
          }).subscribe((result) => {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(result.data);
            const a = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
            a.href = url;
            a.download = result.filename + ".jpg";
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            a.remove();
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

so at console.log(sub.base64Image) it returns 59 images but it downloads only 10. How can i download all of them?

Comment: can you show us the data? and can you reproduce this example on stackblitz.com?

Comment: I cant upload the data. but I can create an example

Comment: If you look at the network tab of your browser debugger tool, does it make 59 requests? Do all requests return a status 200?

Comment: @H.Hakvoort yes it does. I just checked the requests tab! but downloading files are only 15. and from 59 request it does return 200 OK status